# Equivalence between function being Morse and $df$ being transversal to zero section.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, morse-theory

The proof I know of the fact that

> $f:M \to \mathbb{R}$ is Morse iff  $df:M \to T^*M$ is transversal to the zero section

uses local coordinates heavily. I would like to know if there is an intrinsic approach. Since both $df$ and $\mathrm{Hess}$ at a critical point admit fairly intrinsic definitions, I would hope so.

Comment: What do you mean by "intrinsic approach" here? If you want to write down an explicit proof, you need to do some computation using local coordinate..

Comment: @AnubhavMukherjee I mean one which avoids precisely what you say can't be avoided: specific computations using local coordinates.

Comment: This is my favorite definition, actually, @Aloizio. The notion you need is that of *intrinsic derivative* of a section of vector bundle at a zero. I've written about it on at least a few questions here.

Comment: @TedShifrin Hi! Do you mean the split of $T_{(p,0)}T^*M$ in vertical/horizontal? If so, I don't know how to reconcile the definitions even then.

Comment: You can check that the intrinsic derivative of $df$ will give you the Hessian. And you can avoid local coordinates if you have alternative definitions. But, yeah, at a zero $p$ of a section of $E$, the intrinsic derivative is a well-defined $1$-form (at $p$) with values in $E$.

Comment: @TedShifrin By "the intrinsic derivative of $df$ will give you the Hessian", following the definition of Hessian at a critical point $p$ as the usual $\mathrm{Hess}_p:T_pM \times T_pM \to \mathbb{R}$, you mean that the induced map $\widetilde{\mathrm{Hess}}: T_pM \to T_pM^*$ is equal to the map $(D df)_p:T_pM \to T^v_{(p,0)}T^*M$ after identifying the vertical space with $T_pM^*$?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to find an answer directly using the identifications I outlined in the comments (thanks to @TedShifrin for the comments!). Namely, I wasn't able to prove that $(D_vdf)_p:T_pM \to T^v_{(p,0)}T^*M \simeq T_pM^*$ is equal to $\widetilde{\mathrm{Hess}}_pf:T_pM \to T_pM^*$ without coordinates and directly. Therefore, I will leave the question open in hopes of someone doing that.

But with the advent of a connection on $M$, I was able to get more machinery in order to do this intrinsically more easily.

Recall that a connection on $M$ induces a connection $\nabla$ on tensors. We will now verify that at a critical point, $(\nabla df)_p=\mathrm{Hess}_pf$.

We can see that since
\begin{align*}
(\nabla df)_p(X,Y)=(\nabla_Ydf)(X)_p=Y_pXf-df_p(\nabla_{Y_p}X)=Y_pXf=\mathrm{Hess}_pf.
\end{align*}

This computation also shows that the Hessian at a critical point indeed does not depend on the connection you take, if defined by $(\nabla df)_p$.

Note that this implies that $\widetilde{\mathrm{Hess}}_pf: \left(v \mapsto \widetilde{\mathrm{Hess}}_pf(v)\right)$ being an isomorphism is equivalent to $(\nabla df)_p: \left(v \mapsto (\nabla_vdf)_p\right)$ being an isomorphism.

Now, with the induced connection on the bundle $T^*M$, we get by definition of the covariant derivative that
$$(\nabla_v df)_p=\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{\tau_{(p,x(t))}^{-1}(df_{x(t) })}{t},$$
where $x(t)$ is a curve adapted to $v$ and $\tau$ is parallel transportation. This gives by definition a vector on $T_{(p,0)}^vT^*M$. It is not difficult to prove that this is precisely $(D_vdf)_p(v)$ (c.f. [Paternain - Geodesic Flows](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0817641440), the part concerning the *connection map* - Definition $1.12$ up to Exercise $1.16$, but generalizing from $TM$ to a bundle $E$.). Thus, the Hessian being non-degenerate is equivalent to $(D_vdf)_p$ being an isomorphism. Since $(D_hdf)_p$ is the identity and when expanded to $T^*M$ is the derivative of the null-section, $(D_vdf)_p$ being an isomorphism is equivalent to $df_p$ being transversal to the null-section.